# How can I search for packages depending on a exact package?

Tags: aptitude

I'm experimenting a bit with aptitude search terms and finally discovered how to do search on dependencies, which is:

```
aptitude search '?depends("searchterm")'
```

The only problem that I've found is... that the "searchterm" uses expansions. If I use `aptitude search '?depends("vim")'` it will look for any packages that depends on a package that contains the word `vim` in the start, middle or end. Is there a way that I can match the exact package called `vim` and no other expansion?

Comment: In the case of vim, `aptitude search '?depends("^vim$")'` returns a smaller list than just searching for vim, but I haven't confirmed its doing exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @casey that works for now, but there isn't something to do an exact match?

Comment: @Braiam - you've seen this list of search term patterns before? http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide

Comment: `?narrow(filter, pattern)`?

Comment: @slm yeah, no, it uses `?narrow(?name(vim), ?depends(?name(vim)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument of `?depends`, like any other directive, is a search pattern. The pattern `"vim"` is a regular expression that the package name must contain. To search for an exact package name, you need to anchor the regex: `"^vim$"`.

```
aptitude search '?depends("^vim$")'
aptitude search '?depends(^vim$)'
aptitude search '~D^vim$'
```

You can also use the `?exact-name` directive, but for some reason, at least with aptitude 0.6.6, it's slower.

```
aptitude search '?depends(?exact-name(vim))'
```

Comment: The full list of search terms: http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide